# Calculate Disk Space in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, electron-builder, appimage

I am trying to get free disk space in an electron application targeting linux. I have following code to get free space.

```
const checkDiskSpace = require('check-disk-space').default
checkDiskSpace(path.dirname(__dirname)).then((diskSpace) => {
            console.log(diskSpace);
            successCallback(diskSpace.free);                 
}).catch(failCallback);
```

This one works for .deb but for AppImage and snap package it fails to execute this call. In AppImage, i get the following output.

```
diskPath: undefined
free: 0
size: 0
```

Any idea how can i make it work in these environments ?

Comment: That is correct for `__dirname` on snap, the packege is mounted onto it's own loop device. I assume Appimage is doing a similar thing. What is it your are trying to find the free space of?

Comment: I am downloading content from http and saving it on disk. Need to calculate disk space before persisting

Comment: i do get **__dirname** resolved. ```/tmp/.mount_OmniverAjV1z/resources/app```

Comment: **Update** For AppImage i got it to work by replacing ```__dir``` with application dir. I guess loop device does not allow you to calculate size inside its structure.